# Determine the convergence of this serie

Tags: real-analysis

I want to determinate if this serie converges

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-2n}{1+2n}\right)^{n}$$

I try with the comparision criteria, as $1\leq 4n$ (for $n\geq 1$) then $1-2n \leq 1+2n$ so $(1-2n)^n \leq (1+2n)^n$ now we can express $\frac{(1-2n)^n}{(1+2n)^n}\leq\frac{(1+2n)^n}{(1+2n)^n}=1$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1$ diverges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-2n}{1+2n}\right)^{n}$ diverges. This is my conclusion, any suggestion? Thanks!!!

Comment: Unfortunately this proof doesn't work: being less than a divergent series doesn't imply divergence (and being greater than a convergent series doesn't imply convergence). Hint: what is the limit of the summand as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: ANY series is dominated by a  divergent series.

Comment: You may see that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\bigg(\frac{1-2n}{1+2n}\bigg)^n=\frac{1}{e},$$
and use the fact that for a convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n,$ we have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }a_n=0.$

Comment: @MathRookie2204, actually that limit does not exist, indeed there are two subsequences which have different limits. If $a_n=\left(\dfrac{1-2n}{1+2n}\right)^n,\,$ then $\,a_{2n}\to\dfrac1e$, and $\,a_{2n-1}\to-\dfrac1e\,.$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake @Angelo.